# How can I match a word that isn't certain words?

Tags: regex, perl

Using a Perl or unix regex, how would I capture a word that is not a range of values. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

```
(\w:not('int','long'))
```

Comment: Just in case, when you say 'int' and 'long' do you mean the *strings* 'int' and 'long', or do you have in mind variable types (as in C)? I'm pretty sure you mean the strings, but just in case...

Comment: so wouldn't it be better to talk about sets and not about ranges?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is valid perl syntax, but in "generic" flavor you can say

```
/\b(?!int\b|long\b)\w+\b/
```

If you want to capture the word, put parens around `\w+`, like this

```
/\b(?!int\b|long\b)(\w+)\b/
```

Comment: @Adam: don't you need `(\w+)` to capture what we want to find instead? Or am I confused? (I.e., you need the parens to have the item available in `$1`, no?)

Comment: @Telemachus: Whoops, you are right!  I need more coffee.  I was reading "match" where the letters clearly spelled "capture".

Comment: So would the syntax be /\b(?!int\b|long\b)(\w+)\b/ or /\b((?!int\b|long\b)\w+)\b/?

Comment: Yes, you can add the parens around \w+ if you want to grab the word from $1.

Comment: The final \b is redundant.  \w+ must match at least one word character, and since it's at the end of the regex, will match as many as there are up to the end of the string or a non-word character.

Answer (score 6):

It is generally faster to say:

```
my %exclude = map { $_ => 1 } qw/int long/;
my @words   = grep { not exists $exclude{$_} } /(?:\b|^) (\w+) (?:\b|$)/gx;
```

especially on versions of Perl prior to 5.10 (when alternation got a massive speed increase).

Comment: Nice approach. Thoroughly generic :)